# Cannot read property -1 of Undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js

Was doing the Diagonal Difference code challenge on hackerrank.com and I got this error at the end of my code, the thing is, I don't know where the -1 is coming from...

```
function diagonalDifference(arr) {
  // Write your code here
  var val1 = 0, val2 = 0;

  for(let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    for(let j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
      val1 += arr[i][j];
      i++;
    }
  }
  for(let i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
    for(let j = 2; j => 0; j--) {
      console.log(arr[i][j])
      val2 += arr[i][j];
      i++;
    }
  }
  val1 + val2 < 0 ? -(val1 + val2) : val1 + val2;
}
```

The error is where the val2 += arr[i][j], but since the minimum value of j is 0, where that -1 can be coming from? Here's also the error:

```
console.log(arr[i][j])
                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read property '-1' of undefined
```

Comment: The console.log is returning exactly what I want, but the thing is that I can't return anything cuz of the -1 error...

Comment: Your problem is in the inner loop of the second for loop and it's condition:( let j = 2; j => 0; j--), when j=0 you subtracting 1 from it and entering the loop with j=-1.Change the condition to  j > 0.

Comment: You are incrementing i in the inner loop while it is the counter for the outer loop. I don’t think you want that.

Comment: @Lorav doesn’t subtracting 1 happen before the comparison => 0, so that the loop won’t enter when j is -1?

Comment: @crosen9999 you right , my mistake.

Comment: @crosen9999 Like, I understood how to do it correctly but why I can't do it with a double for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the operator is reversed in this line:

```
for(let j = 2; j => 0; j--) {
```

It should be:

```
for(let j = 2; j >= 0; j--) {
```

(That is, =< should be <=.)

Also, having i++ in the inner loops causes the outer loop to run only once.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function diagonalDifference(arr) {
  // Write your code here
  let val1 = 0, val2 = 0;
  const arrLength = arr.length


  let x = 0;
  for(let y = 0; y < arrLength; y++) {
    val1 += arr[y][x]
    x++
  }

  let x2 = arrLength - 1;
  for(let y2 = 0; y2 < arrLength; y2++) {
    val2 += arr[y2][x2]
    x2--
  }
  
  return Math.abs(val1 - val2)
}
```

Comment: I understood what you did, but why can't I do this with a double for loop?